# How to disable a flag in maven compiler plugin?

Tags: maven, devops, maven-compiler-plugin

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project AusPost: Compilation failure
[ERROR] javac: invalid flag: -s
[ERROR] Usage: javac

I am not providing any tag to the maven compiler plugin in my pom.xml. Still it is throwing error saying invalid flag -s.
How to get rid of this?

POM.XML ->

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: How do you start the Maven build?

Comment: First upgrade your version of maven-compiler-plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `-s` comes for `settings.xml` of maven, but you have to provide more info in order to understand your question.